# Put some ListB into ListA as items, then clear ListB and ListA is gone too

Tags: list, flutter

I have 2 List as I code here.

```
List<Detail> orderDetailList = List();
List<List> allOrders = List();
var result;
String tmpCustomerName;
```

My data came from my database as json, and here is some of my code.

```
await Dio().get(myURL).then((value) async {result = json.decode(value.data)});

for (var item in result) {
  OrdersDetailModel ordersDetailModel = OrdersDetailModel.fromJson(item);
  setState(() {
    orders.add(ordersDetailModel);
    customerName = ordersDetailModel.customerName;
    customerPhone = ordersDetailModel.customerPhone;

    var res2 = json.decode(ordersDetailModel.orderDetail);
    for (var item2 in res2) {
      Detail detail = Detail.fromJson(item2);
      orderDetailList.add(detail);
    }

    allOrders.add(orderDetailList);
    print('before $allOrders');

    if (tmpCustomerName != customerName) {
      orderDetailList.clear();
      print('after $allOrders');
    }
    tmpCustomerName = customerName;
  });
}
```

As I mentioned in my question part, when I use `orderDetailList.clear()` after added it to allOrders, the value in allOrders is gone too so allOrders has only empty list, as you can see I printed 'before' and 'after', the 'before' has value but 'after' does not. What am I doing wrong? Or how can I keep the value inside my allOrders list after clearing orderDetailList list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the clear case of `referencing error`, you are doing. There is a concept called `Shallow` and `Deep` copy.

- **Shallow:** It copies the item, but has some reference of the parent item. So when made any changes to either of them make changes in the other item. **Which you are doing right now**
- **Deep Copy:** This is the copy method, where there is no reference to the parent variable. **Which we have to do**

So, let us quickly jump in the code:

```
    // rather than doing add directly from orderDetailsList
    // we  add the data to the tempList holding the Details list, 
    // and then add it to the data
    for (var item2 in res2) {
      Detail detail = Detail.fromJson(item2);
      orderDetailList.add(detail);
    }
  
    // this will keep the data into the list
    List<Detail> tempList = [];
    
    // traversing the item from orderDetailsList
    orderDetailList.forEach((item) => tempList.add(item));

    // here you add the tempList now holding the data
    allOrders.add(tempList);
```

Read about [List.forEach()](https://www.tutorialkart.com/dart/dart-list-iterate-over-elements/). It will give you some concept clarity about the method.